# Traducción de "of" en el historial de revisiones de preguntas duplicadas

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones, agregar-a-transifex

Siguiendo el formato de [L10n de "to", "from", "with...chosen" y "worth...reputation" en el historial de revisiones](/questions/3201/) y teniendo en cuenta lo mencionado en [¿Quieres ayudar a traducir las cadenas del sitio? Este es el proceso](/questions/3166):

En el historial de ediciones de preguntas marcadas como duplicadas, había notado que la cadena "of" no estaba traducida:

[image: Cadena "of" en preguntas marcadas como duplicadas]

Me encargué de buscar la cadena en [es.traducir.win](https://es.traducir.win/), con los siguientes términos de búsqueda:

- [of \$](https://es.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=of%20%5C%24) (134 resultados)
- [\$ of](https://es.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5C%24%20of) (28 resultados)
- [of](https://es.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=of%20)  (+200 resultados... ¿Realmente está allí?)

Ninguno parece estar relacionado.

También me encargué de revisar en la versión en portugués del sitio y parece ser que el caso es el mismo.

¿Existe esta cadena como para su traducción? De no ser así, ¿es posible agregarla?

Comment: me pasás un link donde aparezca ese texto?

Comment: @g3rv4 [Acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/552413/revisions), [acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/544484/revisions), [acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/535637/revisions)...

Comment: gracias! ahí mandé un PR... es una lástima, pero va a ser simplemente "of" porque lo que viene antes viene de la base de datos

Comment: @g3rv4 ¡Gracias a vos! Entiendo, eso explica que toda la cadena anterior sí esté traducida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originalmente iba a traducir "of" (porque el texto antes viene de la base de datos, por lo que es imposible darle contexto). Pero Adam tuvo la genial idea de simplemente borrar el "of" de la vista.

Así que ahí quedó

Comment: Situaciones extremas requieren medidas extremas (?)